# Label cell as 1 when the sum of the column is 0

Tags: python, pandas

Sample DF:

```
A  B    C D E
UK text 0 0 1
US text 0 0 0 
UK text 1 0 0
US text 0 0 0
CA text 0 0 0
```

Transformed DF:

```
A  B    C D E
UK text 0 0 1
US text 0 0 0 
UK text 1 0 0
US text 0 0 0
CA text 0 0 0
"" "NA" 0 1 0
```

Essentially, I'd like to add a dummy row when the the same of the binary columns is 0.

Here is my attempt but nothing is changing to the value when i run it:

```
df[['C', 'D', 'E']].loc[df.index.max, ['C', 'D', 'E']].sum(axis=0) == 0)] = 1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) a new row with a `1` if all values in a given column are `0`:

```
x = df.loc[:,'C':].sum(axis=0).eq(0).astype(int)
new_row = x.reindex(df.columns).fillna({'A':'', 'B':'NA'})
df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

 A     B    C    D    E
0  UK  text  0.0  0.0  1.0
1  US  text  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  UK  text  1.0  0.0  0.0
3  US  text  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  CA  text  0.0  0.0  0.0
5        NA  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: This makes sense but how would you then incorporate the "NA" input in column "B"?

Comment: Ah i assumed that `NA meant the content waas irrelevant. Let me modify

Comment: Updated @madsthaks